# python SQL parser to get the column name and data type

Tags: python, sql-parser

Im using the python SQL parser to get the table information. Im able to get the table name and schema name.

```
import sqlparse
line = '''
CREATE TABLE public.actor (
    actor_id integer DEFAULT nextval('public.actor_actor_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    last_update timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE public.category (
    category_id integer DEFAULT nextval('public.category_category_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    name character varying(25) NOT NULL,
    last_update timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "sample_schema"."sample_table"
(
    "div_cd" VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
    ,"div_name" VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,"org_cd" VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
    ,"org_name" VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
    ,"team_cd" VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
    ,"team_name" VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL
    ,"personal_cd" VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
    ,"personal_name" VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL
    ,"username" VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
    ,"staff_flg" CHAR(1)  DEFAULT '0'::bpchar ENCODE lzo
    ,"leader_flg" CHAR(1)  DEFAULT '0'::bpchar ENCODE lzo
)
DISTSTYLE EVEN
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "sample_schema"."ref_table"
(
     "staff_flg" CHAR(1)  DEFAULT '0'::bpchar SORTKEY ENCODE lzo 
    ,"leader_flg" CHAR(1)  DEFAULT '0'::bpchar ENCODE lzo
)
DISTSTYLE EVEN
;
'''
parse = sqlparse.parse(line)
print([str(t) for t in parse[0].tokens if t.ttype is None][0])

Output: 
public.actor
```

But if I want to return the column name and the data type which token I can use for printing both the two DDL.

The output is something like this,[not exactly the same :)]

```
table: public.actor
```

print column name and data type one by one(maybe in a for loop)

```
column: actor_id
date type: integer
column: first_name
data type: character varying
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code documented inline

```
import sqlparse

line = '''
CREATE TABLE public.actor (
    actor_id integer DEFAULT nextval('public.actor_actor_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    first_name character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    last_name character varying(45) NOT NULL,
    last_update timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE public.category (
    category_id integer DEFAULT nextval('public.category_category_id_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
    name character varying(25) NOT NULL,
    last_update timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "sample_schema"."sample_table"
(
    "div_cd" VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
    ,"div_name" VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,"org_cd" VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL
    ,"org_name" VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
    ,"team_cd" VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL
    ,"team_name" VARCHAR(120) NOT NULL
    ,"personal_cd" VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL
    ,"personal_name" VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL
    ,"username" VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL
    ,"staff_flg" CHAR(1)  DEFAULT '0'::bpchar ENCODE lzo
    ,"leader_flg" CHAR(1)  DEFAULT '0'::bpchar ENCODE lzo
)
DISTSTYLE EVEN
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "sample_schema"."ref_table"
(
     "staff_flg" CHAR(1)  DEFAULT '0'::bpchar SORTKEY ENCODE lzo 
    ,"leader_flg" CHAR(1)  DEFAULT '0'::bpchar ENCODE lzo
)
DISTSTYLE EVEN
;
'''

def get_table_name(tokens):
    for token in reversed(tokens):
        if token.ttype is None:
            return token.value
    return " "

parse = sqlparse.parse(line)
for stmt in parse:
    # Get all the tokens except whitespaces
    tokens = [t for t in sqlparse.sql.TokenList(stmt.tokens) if t.ttype != sqlparse.tokens.Whitespace]
    is_create_stmt = False
    for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
        # Is it a create statements ?
        if token.match(sqlparse.tokens.DDL, 'CREATE'):
            is_create_stmt = True
            continue
        
        # If it was a create statement and the current token starts with "("
        if is_create_stmt and token.value.startswith("("):
            # Get the table name by looking at the tokens in reverse order till you find
            # a token with None type
            print (f"table: {get_table_name(tokens[:i])}")

            # Now parse the columns
            txt = token.value
            columns = txt[1:txt.rfind(")")].replace("\n","").split(",")
            for column in columns:
                c = ' '.join(column.split()).split()
                c_name = c[0].replace('\"',"")
                c_type = c[1]  # For condensed type information 
                # OR 
                #c_type = " ".join(c[1:]) # For detailed type information 
                print (f"column: {c_name}")
                print (f"date type: {c_type}")
            print ("---"*20)
            break
```

Output:

```
table: public.actor
column: actor_id
date type: integer
column: first_name
date type: character
column: last_name
date type: character
column: last_update
date type: timestamp
------------------------------------------------------------
table: public.category
column: category_id
date type: integer
column: name
date type: character
column: last_update
date type: timestamp
------------------------------------------------------------
table: "sample_schema"."sample_table"
column: div_cd
date type: VARCHAR(2)
column: div_name
date type: VARCHAR(30)
column: org_cd
date type: VARCHAR(8)
column: org_name
date type: VARCHAR(60)
column: team_cd
date type: VARCHAR(2)
column: team_name
date type: VARCHAR(120)
column: personal_cd
date type: VARCHAR(7)
column: personal_name
date type: VARCHAR(300)
column: username
date type: VARCHAR(6)
column: staff_flg
date type: CHAR(1)
column: leader_flg
date type: CHAR(1)
------------------------------------------------------------
table: "sample_schema"."ref_table"
column: staff_flg
date type: CHAR(1)
column: leader_flg
date type: CHAR(1)
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Is it possible to print full data type?  like `character varying` , `timestamp without time zone`

Comment: @Bhuvanesh as mentioned in the code use `c_type = " ".join(c[1:]) # For detailed type information ` (uncomment the line) to print the detailed type information

Comment: Yeah, but it is printing everything after the column name, Is SQLparser having ay token to get the exact datatype?

Comment: No, you will have to do string parsing on the tokens, I do not think there is a way to identify the datatype because parser does not have semantics of datatype.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a function from a [script](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/blob/master/examples/column_defs_lowlevel.py) available in python-sqlparse examples to extract the data:

```
def extract_definitions(token_list):
    # assumes that token_list is a parenthesis
    definitions = []
    tmp = []
    par_level = 0
    for token in token_list.flatten():
        if token.is_whitespace:
            continue
        elif token.match(sqlparse.tokens.Punctuation, '('):
            par_level += 1
            continue
        if token.match(sqlparse.tokens.Punctuation, ')'):
            if par_level == 0:
                break
            else:
                par_level += 1
        elif token.match(sqlparse.tokens.Punctuation, ','):
            if tmp:
                definitions.append(tmp)
            tmp = []
        else:
            tmp.append(token)
    if tmp:
        definitions.append(tmp)
    return definitions
```

and use for-loop to print information about columns names and their data types:

```
parsed = sqlparse.parse(line)[0]

# extract the parenthesis which holds column definitions
_, par = parsed.token_next_by(i=sqlparse.sql.Parenthesis)
columns = extract_definitions(par)

for column in columns:
    print(f"column: {column[0]}")
    print(f"data type: {' '.join(str(t) for t in column[1:])}")
```

This code produces the following output:

```
column: actor_id
data type: integer DEFAULT nextval 'public.actor_actor_id_seq' :: regclass NOT NULL
column: first_name
data type: character varying 45 NOT NULL
column: last_name
data type: character varying 45 NOT NULL
column: last_update
data type: timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now NOT NULL
```

It is actually a little bit more information than you wanted. However, those strings should be easily ''regexable'' to extract only basic data types.

As already mentioned in comments, using special information (e.g. `DISTSTYLE`) causes parser not to recognize `sqlparse.sql.Parenthesis` instance and was reported as a [bug](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/issues/428). Thus, such information needs to be removed from the SQL query before parsing.

Comment: Yes, I saw this, but its not working if I have some special information like DISTRIBUTION STYLE  (the last SQL statement from the DDL query), its giving this error
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'flatten'`

Comment: You are right. This situation requires the removal of such special information from `line` in order to work. Notice that this bug [has already been reported](https://github.com/andialbrecht/sqlparse/issues/428).